# I can't style properly on react-native

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to change the background color and align the items on the center, so I tried this:

```
<View style={Stylesheet.container}>

            <TouchableOpacity style={Stylesheet.button} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Register")}>
                Register
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity style={Stylesheet.button} onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Login")}>
                Login
            </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

The file with the styles is correct, I know that because it works on the TouchableOpacity and it is here:

```
import { StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

const Stylesheet = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        color: '#141414',
        backgroundColor: '#141414',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: '100vh',
        display: 'flex'
    },

    button: {
        fontSize: '20px',
        backgoundColor: 'white',
        color: '#f63364',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: '20px'
    }
})

export default Stylesheet
```

But when I add the styling inline, it works fine

```
(...)
<View style={Stylesheet.container, { flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#141414'}}>
(...)
```

How is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Give container `flex` value of `1`:

```js
const Stylesheet = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex:1,
        color: '#141414',
        backgroundColor: '#141414',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: '100vh',
    },

    button: {
        fontSize: '20px',
        backgoundColor: 'white',
        color: '#f63364',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        padding: '20px'
    }
})
```